# $X, Y$ iid, If $(\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}})$ has the same distribution as $(X, Y)$, then $X$ is a normal r.v.

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

$X$ is s.t. $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0, \mathbb{E}(X^{2}) < \infty$. $X, Y$ are i.i.d.

If $(\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}})$ has the same distribution as $(X, Y)$, then $X$ is a normal r.v.

Where should I start? Appreciate any hint!

Comment: Your first bet should be to deduce as many facts about the characteristic function of $X$ as possible.

Comment: In particular, what is $\varphi_X(2u)?$

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think by a theorem I can write $\phi(t) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}t^{2}\mathbb{E}(X^{2}) + o(t)t^{2}$

Comment: $(X+Y)/\sqrt 2$ has the same characteristic function as $X$, and so does $(X-Y)/\sqrt 2$, which is also independent. So...

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ah I remember something. Is it CLT?